Equivalent condition of commutativity between derivative operator and contraction in a differential manifold
For a differential manifold $M$, a derivative operator is a map $\nabla: \mathscr{F}_M(k,l) \to \mathscr{F}_M(k,l+1)$ that satisfies the following conditions:

Linearity
Leibniz Rule
Commutativity with Contraction
$ v(f) = v^a \nabla_a f, \, \forall f \in \mathscr{F}_M, \, v \in \mathscr{F}_M(1,0) $

Please show that condition (3) is equivalent to $ \nabla_a {\delta^b}_c = 0 $, where $ {\delta^b}_c \in \mathscr{F}_M(1,1) $ and $ {\delta^b}_c v^c = v^b, \, \forall v^c \in \mathscr{F}_M(1,0) $.
The necessity has been proven as follows, but I am unsure how to approach the sufficiency:

For any given $ v^a \in \mathscr{F}_M(1,0) $, we have:
$$
\nabla_a v^b = \nabla_a C({\delta^b}_c v^d) = C(\nabla_a ({\delta^b}_c v^d)) = C(v^d \nabla_a {\delta^b}_c) + C({\delta^b}_c \nabla_a v^d) = v^c \nabla_a {\delta^b}_c + \nabla_a v^b,
$$
where $C$ denote the contraction between the $c$ "slot" and the $d$ "slot".
Thus, we find that $ v^c \nabla_a {\delta^b}_c = 0 $. Due to the arbitrariness of $ v^a $, we conclude that $ \nabla_a {\delta^b}_c = 0 $.

